# jQuery - Check if element is hidden before showing it or just show it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What is the correct (fastest/safest) approach to showing an element with jQuery?  Should I be checking first if the element is hidden before showing it or is it faster and just as safe to just go ahead and show the element and jQuery will take care of the rest (ie: do nothing if the element is already visisble)?

Comment: Just call `.show()` - no need to check

Comment: Just show, if it's not visible it will become visible, if it's visible it will remain visible. The performance penalty of checking for visibility is more of cost than any benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no harm in just calling `.show`, even if the element is showing.